# Google token randomly deleted

Tags: c#, google-api

In my app, I have saved my user-credentials to a path, with the file-name `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user`

This is the default file that the `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` method (part of the Auth.OAuth2 API) searches for, right?

It only picks up the credentials when saved to this file name, and creates a new one when not.

Yesterday, this was working fine, and the API was using this file properly, but today, it seems to be randomly deleting it.

I say random, as it confusingly deletes at different places within code--I pain-stakingly stepped through my code, at-least 10 times.

It does delete only after the credential is loaded.

Why is this happening? Is there a background asynchronous process by Google which might be deleting this because it's invalid?

The structure of the file:

```
{
  "access_token" : *string*,
  "expires_in" : *int*,
  "id_token" : *string*,
  "refresh_token" : *string*,
  "token_type" : "*string*
}
```